# How does this program in python work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am new to Python and I am stuck at the following code:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for number in numbers:
    print numbers
```

When I run this program, it prints the `numbers` sequence 10 times. How does this happen?
I still haven't assigned a value to the variable `number`, so how does it check whether the number is in the range? As far as I know, the variable `number` has a null value.

Comment: `for` binds the variable `numbers` for you.

Comment: It prints the list of numbers 10 times because you are printing `numbers` rather than `number`. See the accepted answer for an explanation as to how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is the most basic for loop.

In a more general way, let's say you have a list `L`, with elements `L1, L2, L3, L4, L5`.

In Python, that is:

```
L = [L1, L2, L3, L4, L5]
```

Now if you loop through your list `L`, like this:

```
for element in L:
    print element
```

The variable `element` (which you have never assigned before!) will automatically be assigned to the value of the first element of the list `L`, which is `L1`. Then, in my example, this value, `L1`, will be printed.

After that, there are still other elements in the list! So the program will change the value of the variable `element`, and set it to the value of the second element of the list `L`, `L2`. Then it will print the value of `element` (so, `L2`), or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a `for` loop:

```
for x in y:
```

this automatically assigns each value from the iterable `y`, in turn, to the variable name `x`.

You could add `print number` to your code to see what is happening on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your print `numbers` instead of `number`.